# Where are the tk style customization saved/stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Take this very simple code sample:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
    
root = tk.Tk()
    
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('vista')
s.map("Mod.TCombobox",fieldbackground=[('readonly', 'red')])
```

Can you tell me where the `Mod.TCombobox` custom style is saved or stored?
I mean, is there a way to retrieve the list of all defined style options available? (Both 'standard' and 'custom' ones possibly).

I tried looking on the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

(P.S. I tried having a look at `s.element_names()` but, no surprise, it isn't there...)

EDIT:

To clarify a little, in first place, I'm not asking for the list of themes available (I know that can be obtained using the command `s.theme_names()`).

That said, suppose I define a new rule now, like for instance:

```py
s.map("Mod.TEntry",fieldbackground=[('readonly', 'red')])
```

What I'm asking is: **is there a command or any way for me to retrieve a list of custom defined tk style rules**, such as ['Mod.TCombobox', 'Mod.TEntry'] in this case? (Whenever possible, I'd settle even for a listing with both custom and non-custom style rules definitions, having my custom defined styles mixed among/together with "standard" ones, such as 'TCombobox', 'TEntry', etc...).

In the same way, when using the style layout command, like for instance:

```py
s.layout('MyCustomTCB', s.layout('TCombobox'))
```

As second part of the question: **where or how can I retrieve a list containing all the custom style layout I created?**

(P.S. Even I'm not asking that here, I want to thank Bryan Oakley that provided me the link to [ttk library source code](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/tree/main/library/ttk) which, for sure, can be very useful to look at for what concerns with standard built-in tk themes style rules and layout.)

Using Python `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your title *Where are tk style customization saved/stored?* is written in [TIP 48](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/48.md) and it is stated the:

> Current implementation uses **thread-local storage** for holding dynamic
> data. Since most data is not thread-specific, this could be changed to
> a more memory-efficient scheme.

To address your other question if it is possible to retrieve a list of defined styles. I did not find a obvious way to do so, neither in the defined methods out of the TIP 48, or the [style manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_style.html), nor does the [source code](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/ttk/defaults.tcl) indicate such a list.